# PreMailer "Method Not Found" (AngleSharp.Dom.IElement.RemoveAttribute)

Tags: c#, asp.net, methodnotfound, anglesharp, premailer

I have this code which inlines CSS using PreMailer;

```
PreMailer.Net.PreMailer cleanser = new PreMailer.Net.PreMailer(htmlString);
PreMailer.Net.InlineResult result = cleanser.MoveCssInline(ignoreElements: ".ignore");
return result.Html
```

But I'm getting this exception:

> Method not found: 'Void AngleSharp.Dom.IElement.RemoveAttribute(System.String)'

Stack Trace

```
[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void AngleSharp.Dom.IElement.RemoveAttribute(System.String)'.]
PreMailer.Net.StyleClassApplier.ApplyStyles(IElement domElement, StyleClass clazz) +0
PreMailer.Net.StyleClassApplier.ApplyAllStyles(Dictionary`2 elementDictionary) +125
PreMailer.Net.PreMailer.MoveCssInline(Boolean removeStyleElements, String ignoreElements, String css, Boolean stripIdAndClassAttributes, Boolean removeComments) +241
```

The answer is probably really obvious but I'm just not clicking on.

AngleSharp: v0.9.9

PreMailer: v1.5.4

Comment: https://github.com/milkshakesoftware/PreMailer.Net/issues/128

Comment: Ahh I didn't check the closed section. Not important, just wondering, is there's a solution that doesn't involve rolling back AngleSharp to 0.9.5?

Comment: See update from martinnormark in the linked issue..

Comment: Thanks. Update coming soon!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been an update released for PreMailer. Upgrade to 1.5.5 to resolve this issue! No rollback for AngleSharp required!